# Disable line number mode for compilation mode

Tags: compilation-mode, line-numbers

I have set multiple modes to not show `display-line-number-mode` and recently I added `compilation-mode` to that list, but the `compilation-mode` still shows line numbers. Here is the relevant code,

```
  ;; Disable line numbers for some modes
  (dolist (mode '(org-mode-hook
                  term-mode-hook
                  shell-mode-hook
                  treemacs-mode-hook
                  eshell-mode-hook
                  vterm-mode-hook
                  compilation-mode        ;; <----
                  telega-root-mode-hook
                  telega-chat-mode-hook
                  erc-mode-hook))
    (add-hook mode (lambda () (display-line-numbers-mode 0))))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't you have a typo? Shouldn't it be `compilation-mode-hook`?

Comment: try `(display-line-numbers-mode -1)`

Comment: @SwarnenduBiswas Yes, it was a silly mistake, I missed `-hook`. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was based on a typo and not likely to be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

It was `compilation-mode-hook` instead of `compilation-mode`.

Comment: As an aside, I think if you'd named your variable `hook` (for what it was) instead of `mode` (which it wasn't), you might well have spotted that yourself.